# Grub fails, can't install lubuntu

Tags: system-failure

The story is that I had dual boot option with win8 and debian jessie by grub.  Now its over.

I was running debian when i pressed a button which by 1 keystroke darkens the screen and i left it so, and (after a time) the system got hybernated. I did it because i wanted to use my laptop as a music stand to keep the sheets during i am playing the guitar, and the screen was too bright. xD But the laptop has taken revenge...

When i pressed that button again, i encountered a vibrating screen (black and white). Its strange but by phisically moving (bending) the screen it stopped and i could use the system. I saved all the important files to another machine. Yet 2 times i was able to boot debian but no more. (white screen saying unable to start the system and i should log out although i didnt even log in).

Windows was still working, no vibrating and Disk Management showed that the partition of debian was in perfect condition. But  I couldn't fix the problem of debian with Super grub2 disk and i decided to install lubuntu instead of debian. Deleting and formatting the  partion of debian i tried to install lubuntu but i couldn't. It failed to install grub2 into the /target/ directory. It wasn't depending on which partition i say it to intall on. I couldn't choose the option "install grub later", nor interrupt the installation but it didn't freeze. I had to power it off manually.
Now i cant even start win8.

Notices when dual boot was working:
- at system start debian failed to load backlight controller
- first i had win8, then i shrinked the partion to get a new one for debian
- after installing debian windows' wifi connection became slow but debian's connection was ok

Any advice? Now i am planning to delete everything and just use 1 os as host, namely lubuntu but i thouht this problem worthes a question.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I regained windows with my bootfiles and thanks to 2 commands (bootrec /fixmbr, and bootrec /fixboot)

Comment: I'll take it to the service. Now windows flickers too. I'll write down the result later.

Comment: It was a contact error, thus a hardware problem. (The experienced differences between the the OSes maybe just were coincidences.)